# WP-login.php is Redirecting to the wrong URL

Tags: php, wordpress

By mistake I have installed a php script in my root directory, where wordpress is available. After that all my permalinks have been changed. After I modified .htaccess file and permissions file by ftp, now  [my site](http://www.investorsbd.com) site is almost OK.

Still, I can't log-in admin panel. When I supply admin user name and password, the url I am redirected to is http://investorsbd.com/index.php/wp-login.php (extra index.php has shown) and says nothing found for index php login.

How can I remove that extra index.php for log-in my wordpress admin control panel?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your .htacess file with below code

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

else try this code

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /dwellingventures/dwelling/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . http://investorsbd.com/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary fix, but if you click the forgot password link and then enter your email and then login it will work.

More permanently, we found it easier to link directly to wp-login rather than wp-admin.